# Lodash: chunk by pattern matching at end of string

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have a file format that looks as follows.

> ' this is a comment
>   #method1
>   XQ#1234
>   END
>   
>   #method2
>   XR#1234
>   HR#9620
>   END

My goal is to chunk, but on a look ahead to each instance of `END`.

```
var instructions = _(fs.readdirSync(filepath))
  .filter((file) => _.endsWith(file, '.assembly'))
  .map((filename) => fs.readFileSync(path.join(filepath, filename)).toString('ascii').split('\n'))
  .flatten()
  .reject((str) => /^\s*$|^[\\\'\"].*/g.test(str))
  // ^ the contents of the files with the comments and blank lines removed.
  // here is where I get lost
  .chunk( /** ??? */ )
```

The end goal is to have something like this:

```
[ ['XQ#1234'], ['XR#1234', 'HR#9620'] ]
```

The main problem I am having is chunking the arrays based on every instance of "END", rather than having two delimiters to work with (eg, `BEGIN` and `END`). I figure there must be some usage of `_.findIndex` to help with this.

How can you chunk on an occurrence of a string based on an ending delimiter in lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a split function:

```
_.mixin({"split": function(arr, f) {
    return _.reduce(arr, function(r, x) {
       if(f(x)) {
           r.push([]);
       } else {
           r[r.length - 1].push(x)
       }
       return r;
    }, [[]]);
}});
```

And use it like this:

```
var instructions = _(fs.readdirSync(filepath))
  .filter((file) => _.endsWith(file, '.assembly'))
  .map((filename) => fs.readFileSync(path.join(filepath, filename)).toString('ascii').split('\n'))
  .flatten()
  .reject((str) => /^\s*$|^[\\\'\"].*/g.test(str))
  .split((str) => "END" == str)
```

Or if you don't want a add a new mixin to lodash:

```
...
.reject((str) => /^\s*$|^[\\\'\"].*/g.test(str))
.reduce(function(r, x) {
   if("END" == x) {
       r.push([]);
   } else {
       r[r.length - 1].push(x)
   }
   return r;
}, [[]]);
```

Comment: ah, knew I wanted a `split`, but thought it was bizarre that lodash didn't supply it by default.